# python recursion global Name is not defined Compilation error

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

I'm trying to make recursion function.

```
class Solution(object):
    def twoSum(self, nums, target):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :type target: int
        :rtype: List[int]
        """
        print(nums,target)
        nums.sort()
        mid = len(nums)/2
        if target < nums[mid]: 
            return twoSum(nums[:mid],target)
        else:
            for i in range(len(nums)):
                if sum(nums[i:i+1]) == target:
                    return [i,i+1]
```

I got the compilation error with 
global name 'twoSum' is not defined
do I have initial the twoSum function somewhere globally?

Comment: It's an instance method, so `self.toSum`. It's unclear *why* it's in a class, though.